# Startup Profiles

Tags: startup-file

I am new to Blender and loving it. I have a request for a feature that at least for me would be a huge asset. I would like to have the ability to select from different startup files. Right now my only choice is to save current or load factory settings. I have different workflows that would benefit from having the ability to easily swap out what startup configuration I need for what ever I am doing. Currently the only way I have found to do this is to create my config folder backup, save it to a different location and then swap them out based on my needs. So where would I properly post this request?

Comment: Hi Kevin did you take a look at the Application Templates section in the Blender Manual? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender has a feature called [*Application Templates*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html), which allow you to create custom re-usable project configurations tailored to your needs.

In order to create your own *Application Template*, you need to create a .blend project with the interface configurations that you like and optionally a Python script which is executed when the startup file is loaded. For detailed instructions see the following [answer on Blender's StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152673/new-default-file-template/152677#152677).

Existing *Application Templates* can be used to create a new project using *File > New* in Blender.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can work with this and make it work for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but, there are some workspaces that you can customize according to your needs. If that's not the case, go to https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: I did try doing this but the bigger thing is I have custom colors setup for each of these layouts which give me an instant que as to what workflow I currently started Blender with. Also I have specific addons that are setup to run for each, so just adding a workspace does not go deep enough into the changes I need but thanks for offering to help.