# How to save the default mode of a custom workspace?

Tags: startup-file, workspaces

When designing new workspaces, there doesn't seem to be a way to save or define the default mode of that workspace.  You can duplicate one of the presets and go from there, which would work fine... but there isn't a preset for painting Vertices, even though this is one of the selectable modes.

Currently it would seem to be impossible to create a vertex painting workspace.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want an application template https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152673/new-default-file-template

Comment: There is no need for a new template, you can easily set it from the UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either from the *3D View Sidebar > Tools* tab or from the *Properties Window > Active Tool* tab there is a workspace panel.

The dropdown menu allows you to define a default workspace mode. After that save the startup file from the *File > Defaults > Save Startup File* menu entry so it is available next time you start a new session.

[image]