# read_factory_settings makes all other operators call fail in a python script ran at startup

Tags: python, mesh, import, operator

I want to read a ply mesh at blender startup using a python script given in the command line:
`blender --python load_ply.py`.

My script `load_ply.py` basically looks like this:

```
import bpy

# This line is the issue:
# bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True) 

bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath='mesh.ply')
```

It works fine until I use `bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)` to clear the scene before the import, which gives the following error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/scripts/addons/io_mesh_ply/__init__.py", line 87, in execute
    context.window.cursor_set('WAIT')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor_set'

location: /path/to/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:132
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/scripts/addons/io_mesh_ply/__init__.py", line 87, in execute
    context.window.cursor_set('WAIT')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor_set'

location: /path/to/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:132

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/script/load_ply.py", line 5, in <module>
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply(filepath='mesh.ply')
  File "/path/to/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/scripts/addons/io_mesh_ply/__init__.py", line 87, in execute
    context.window.cursor_set('WAIT')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor_set'

location: /path/to/blender/blender-2.92.0-linux64/2.92/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:132
```

What is the meaning of this error?
What change does the `read_factory_settings` operator bring?

I use blender 2.92.0 on Debian 10.

A basic file `mesh.ply`:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 8
property float32 x
property float32 y
property float32 z
element face 6
property list uint8 int32 vertex_index
end_header
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
4 0 1 2 3
4 7 6 5 4
4 0 4 5 1
4 1 5 6 2
4 2 6 7 3
4 3 7 4 0
```

Comment: AIUI it throws out the current file, including state for the current script. Easiest fix is to pass `--factory-startup` on the command line instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Separate into two scripts..**

As commented by @scurest the read factory settings operator, naffs the contest, in this case `context.window` becoming `None` and throwing the error as shown.

Would either make a `read_factory.py` script

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)
```

and with script as above (read factory settings commented out) (`-P` is equiv of `--python`)

```
blender -P read_factory.py -P load_ply.py
```

Opening a new file with just your imported ply mesh.  (Whereas starting with --factory-startup results in default startup objects and imported mesh)

For me the issue with doing this is my eyesight isn't what it used to be, and need everything a wee bit larger than default.

Another way would be to save an empty `blank.blend`  Could make your startup file blank.

```
blender -P load_ply.py blank.blend
```

downside being if accidentally saved rather than save as is no longer blank.

Similar option is making a blank [application template](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html)

[New default file template?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152673/new-default-file-template)

(Note can add to your user config folder, eg on linux  `~/.config/blender/2.90/scripts/startup/bl_app_templates_user/blank/`)

```
blender --app-template blank -P load_ply.py
```

other options commonly seen is removing or unlinking all collections / objects from scene / blend,

[How to completely remove all loaded data from Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46990/how-to-completely-remove-all-loaded-data-from-blender)