# Initialize totally empty background instance of Blender

Tags: python, command-line

I'm using Blender python api as one part of a larger pipeline, to convert between Collada versions (1.5 --> 1.4).  The simple script is this:

```
import bpy
import sys

argv = sys.argv

dae_in = argv[4]
dae_out = argv[5]

bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=dae_in)
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath=dae_out)
```

This little scriptlet is itself wrapped in a bigger `subprocess` call in a much longer script, farming it out to Blender's python instance to handle just this conversion piece.

It works fine but somewhat amusingly, even a background instance of blender appears to *still load the default cube model* into memory.

What is the command line option to get a background instance of blender without the cube?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219252/15543

Comment: why don't you just delete the default cube with python!?

Comment: Hi Chris, that sounds GREAT.  Why don't you tell me how to do that with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the head of your script.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```